# how to use for loop varaible in action listener

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm attempting to use a for loop to generate and add ActionListeners for jButtons along with some fancy array editing and random array grabbing

this uses some custom function (all of which work)

```
for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
     //make new jButton with function button to set it up
     JButton newGenButton = button(0, (i+1)*20, 100, (i+2)*20,data[i][0][1]);
     //add action listner
     newGenButton.addActionListener(
     new ActionListener(){  
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
           //empty string
           String gen = "";
           //this gets the name (data[i][i2][0]) and uses the ran function to get another random string from the array (data[i][i2])
           for(int i2 = 1; i2 < data.length; i2++){
              gen+= data[i][i2][0]+": "+ran(data[i][i2])+"\n\n";
           }
           //this add the text to pre-defined JTextArea
           text.setText(gen);
        }  
     });
  }
```

the reference functions are here if it useful

```
  private static JButton button(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, String text){
     JButton newButton = new JButton(text);
     newButton.setBounds(x1,y1,x2-x1,y2-y1);
     dp("button \""+text+"\" built");
     return newButton;
  }
  private static String ran(String[] input) {
     return input[1+rand.nextInt(input.length-1)];
  }
```

when trying to  compile i run across the error

```
Main.java:127: error: local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final
gen+= data[i][i2][0]+": "+ran(data[i][i2])+"\n\n";
           ^
```

in essence what I need is a way to have the action listener know value the int i is, or really just know what data[i][][] is (which is different for each button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract `ActionListener` outside as a class something along the lines:

```
private static class MyActionListener implements ActionListener {

        private int i;

        MyActionListener(int i) {
            this.i = i;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

        }
    }
```

Now when you are adding actionListener to the button, instantiate this class passing in the value of i in the constructor. The logic of your `actionPerformed` remains the same. When adding `actionListener`, simply do the following: `newGenButton.addActionListener(new MyActionListener(i));`

Comment: figured it out, threw error that int i cant be private so I change it to public, works perfectly, thank you

Comment: @Aspwilenson Welcome!